# Play audio files in Java

Tags: java, audio, wav, java-io, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to play a simple audio file which is in the same directory near the  class file. I tried many examples from the internet, but all the others gave me errors which I couldn't even understand.

Then I found this, and I am using it now.

> **There are neither compile errors nor runtime errors. But the problem is I cannot hear any noise.**

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

class A{
    public static void main (String[]args){
        try {
                AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("abc.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
                Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInputStream);
                clip.start();
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
            }
    }
}
```

[image: screen-shot]

**Please note that my system volume is 80%, and the audio file plays in VLC media player.**

Comment: Can you hear it from the VLC player or does it just play?

Comment: Yes. I have mentioned that in the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting the audio clip does not block the main method. So

```
 clip.start();
```

starts playing and then returns. Now your main method ends and therefore the Java process ends. No sound.

If you do

```
 clip.start();
 Thread.sleep(20000);
```

you should hear the clip playing for 20 seconds.

So for a working program just must make sure that the main thread does not end as long as you want to play the clip.

Comment: Understood very well, Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Hold the thread for a while until the audio clip plays.

```
long audioPlayTime = 1000; //clip duration in miliseconds.
try {
           Thread.sleep(audioPlayTime);
} catch (InterruptedException ex){
            //TODO
}
```